# SA_RESTART - why should the primitives fail?

Tags: signals, flags

I've been reading the sigaction() function and came across this reference:
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_498.html
Now, the second sentence states:

> If the signal handler returns, the system faces the question: what should happen next?

I don't understand what is the problem - if the signal handler does its job and returns, what's the big deal? Especially if it doesn't interrupt the process execution? Why would any primitives have to fail and why is the SA_RESTART flag needed?